# Making a quiz in HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some extreme help with making a quiz in HTML. My point is to have a HTML page on the web that people can visit, fill in a quiz, and the data will be stored. Now, I have no knowledge what so ever about how to do this, all I know is what I need to do. I understand that I'm pretty much asking you guys to do the heavy lifting for me, but I need to do this for tomorrow and I can't simply learn everything in a few hours. I've tried to do some stuff, but didn't really work out. So, if you are willing to do the programming for me, here is what I need:

- A form that asks the user for his age (he inputs the number equivalent to his age);
- a multiple choice form that asks the user if he is male or female (maybe even a dropdown menu, either of them are fine);
- a multiple choice form that asks the user how much time he spends on pc, the choices being: 0-2 hours, 2-4, 4-8, 8-12, and +12 hours.

Again, usually I would be trying to learn HTML from scratch and doing this on my own, but I need to do this as fast as humanly possible, so if one of you HTML/javascript programmers can give me a hand, I would much appreciate it. I have a free subdomain on freehostingeu.com where I can host the HTML. Also, I would like to be able to store the choices of the user so I can analyze them afterwards.

PS: I am not used to posting here, so sorry if I'm doing something wrong, you can always mention it on your reply. If I'm forgetting to mention something important, tell me so I can add it in as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is off topic since you have no code.  But one thing I can say is you will need more than HTML and Javascript if you want to store the results for later. Go learn PHP or JSP or one of the other server-side languages in addition to Javascript and HTML.

Comment: Google Forms might be your best option

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The point of this site is to discuss problems commonly encountered while coding. You won't have much luck finding someone here that will write all your code for you. When you try it yourself and get stuck, that's when you should post here.

Comment: Question is far too broad. You should try to implement this and try to solve each of the problems, one by one. You just basically asked for a complete solution, you need a developer, not an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website is for people that intend to program or already do, I don't believe asking for code is allowed.

Anyways, you might be interested on [Google Forms](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/createforms.html) or [Surveymonkey](http://surveymonkey.com), two of the countless survey serving services for non-programmers.

If you do intend to learn HTML and Javascript, you'll definitely need more time, and you can come here at any time to ask about any doubts you have.

Comment: Thank you. I don't think I will be able to post questions after this though, with that many dislikes. People didn't have to dislike it so much, I didn't know it was forbidden... I will try to check those out @Kroltan and see If I can make a functioning form.

Comment: Oh you will be able to, you can't get less than 1 reputation (required for asking questions) unless you get banned, which only happens if you repeat improper questioning. I'd suggest reading this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Follow it closely and you'll get awesome answers!

Comment: thank you again! Also, SurveyMonkey seems to do the job. I will just include a link to it from my main HTML page.

Comment: @user3357221 I'm happy you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you cant learn how to program this form in a couple hours, so you need to resort to services that will allow you to build your form in a WYSIWYG editor (what you see is what you get).

**try [wufoo.com](http://wufoo.com)**

owned by survey monkey so it is legit - their tools are easy to use and should have no issues with your needs. [I am not in any way affiliated with wufoo.com, but I used their services in the past for a similar need]

Answer (score -1):

Why not try google form?  For simple quiz, it should be enough.
survey monkey probably will do similar things

If you want to build a website to do this, you might need some sort of database to store your data, e.g. mysql, sqlite...   You also need communication to the server, which means you probably need php instead of html to serve your goal.  Anyway, if you are totally new, it is hard to finish in a day.  I would suggest something easy and quick like google documents.